# Insert into table and return the Auto Increment Id Assigned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i am inserting information about cars, in three different instances, in the first it goes to auto containing only 4 rows for basic year make model and price and a unique id is set automatically by mysql. great. now how do i return that id that was set for that instance so i can use it to insert it to the other two instances of pictures and attributes?

```
    $toauto = "INSERT INTO auto(year, make, model, mileage, price) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

/*      
        //sql for inserting into auto
        $toattributes = "INSERT INTO attributes(auto_id,
        bodystyle, enginesize, cyl, hp, fuel, transmission, shifts, od, cd, mp3, dvd,
        gps, sound_system, sradio, tachometer, clock, trip, eweather, digitalboard, rwd,
        fwd, awd, fxf, cruisecontrol, tiltsteering, ac, removabletop, keyless, airbags,
        alloy, trunkantitrap, ewindows, emirrors, eseat, elocks, antitheft, leadheadlights
        ) 
        VALUES ($autoid, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        //sql to insert into the pictures
        $topictures = "INSERT INTO auto(year, make, model, mileage, price) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
*/      
        print_r($auto);
        print_r($paths);
        //$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        //inserting to auto
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($toauto);
        $final = array_merge(array_values($auto));
        $sth->execute($final);
/*
        //inserting to attributes
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($toauto);
        $final = array_merge(array_values($auto));
        $sth->execute($final);
        //inserting to pictures
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($toauto);
        $final = array_merge(array_values($auto));
        $sth->execute($final);
*/
```

the row name is `auto_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using PDO, call `$dbh->lastInsertId()` to get the auto increment id from the last insert operation.

Comment: sir can i do this `$autoid = $dbh->lastInsertId()'`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need to do. PDO::lastInsertId() returns the id generated on the last insert.